# How can I test update_attributes function in Rails with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my Rails 4 app I have this `update` action:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def update
    current_email = @user.email
    new_email = user_params[:email].downcase
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      if current_email != new_email
        @user.email = current_email
        @user.new_email = new_email.downcase
        @user.send_email_confirmation_email
        flash[:success] = "Please click the link we've just sent you to confirm your new email address."
      else
        flash[:success] = "User updated."
      end
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

It basically makes sure that a `user` cannot simply save any new email address. He will have to confirm it first by clicking on a link in an email we send to him.

This works great, however, for some reason I haven't found a way to test it.

The following RSpec test keeps failing no matter what I do:

```
it "changes the user's new_email attribute" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => "john@doe.com")
  patch :update, :id => @user, :user => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user, :email => "new@email.com")
  expect(@user.reload.new_email).to eq("new@email.com")
end
```

`@user.new_email` is always `nil` and the test always fails. What am I missing here?

Re-factoring my `update` action wouldn't be a problem at all. Maybe there's a better way? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I would write the spec like so:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "john@doe.com") }

it "changes the user's new_email attribute" do
  expect do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user, email: "new@email.com")
    user.reload
  end.to change(user, :new_email).from("john@doe.com").to("new@email.com")
end
```

When it comes to the controller action itself the problem is that the new_email property is never saved to the database, besides that its kind of a mess. You can clean it up by using [ActiveRecord::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) which tracks attribute changes in the model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # updates user with attrs but moves a new email to the `new_email`
  # column instead
  def update_with_email(attrs, &block)
    update(attrs) do |record|
      if record.email_changed?
        record.new_email = record.email.downcase
        record.restore_attribute!(:email)
      end
      # keeps the method signature the same as the normal update
      yield record if block_given?
    end
  end
end
```

Putting this business logic in the model also lets you test it separatly:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe "#update_with_email" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    it "does not change the email attribute" do
      expect do
        user.update_with_email(email: ”xxx@example.com”)
        user.reload
      end.to_not change(user, :email)
    end

    it "updates the new_email" do
      expect do
        user.update_with_email(email: ”xxx@example.com”)
        user.reload
      end.to change(user, :new_email).to('xxx@example.com')
    end
  end
end
```

This lets you keep the controller nice and skinny:

```
def update
  if @user.update_with_email(user_params)
    if @user.new_email_changed?
      @user.send_email_confirmation_email
      flash[:success] = "Please click the link we've just sent you to confirm your new email address."
    else
      flash[:success] = "User updated."
    end
    # You probably want to redirect the user away from the form instead.
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks very promising and much better than my original code! Unfortunately, I am getting `undefined method 'changed?' for "":String` in my controller in line `if @user.new_email.changed?`. I copied your code word by word. What am I missing?

Comment: I've already tried various things, manually included the `ActiveModel::Dirty` as well, but to no avail. I am using Rails 4.2.8.

Comment: Oh Oops should be .new_email_changed?

Comment: My bad. You don't need to include `ActiveModel::Dirty` as its already included in `ActiveRecord::Base`. It should have been a call to  `.new_email_changed?` instead of calling it on the value of `.new_email`. There was also a mistake in the model spec.

Comment: Thanks. It's really weird but all these `_changed?` methods never seem to get triggered. In the controller `@user.xxxxx_changed?` always returns `false`, no matter what I try. In the model, the `update(attrs) do` block never gets called either. I've done a ton of reading on `ActiveModel::Dirty` as well, so I am running out of ideas.